# AJAX POST Loses Reference to Model Attributes - Spring

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, spring-mvc

I'm submitting a from via an AJAX POST but am losing reference to my @ModelAttribute values which breaks the app. Here's my request (using Alloy UI but the request is very general):

```
 Y.io.request( launches the ajax request
    '/userEditForm/' + userID, //request string which calls the controller
    {
        method: 'GET',
        on: {
           success: function(e) {
                showEditForm();
           },
           failure: function(e) {
                alert(e.error.message);
           }
    }
});
```

I have a request setup to return the user form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userEditForm/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getUserEditForm(@PathVariable Long id){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user");//user.html
    User user = userRepo.findOne(id);
    mav.addObject("user", user);
    return mav; 
}
```

At this point all my Model attributes are populated with values being,

`{user=User [getId()=123, getName()=Bob, getAddress()=54 Little Billy Lane, getPhone()=8457955555, getManager()=Jim Jimson]}`

The form is returned with only the name, address and phone number fields, as I don't want a user update another user's ID or Manager

```
<form action="/saveUser/{id}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
</form>
```

On submit my saveUser `@Controller` is called

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("User") User user, @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        user = userRepo.findOne(id); 
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        userRepo.save(user); 
        return "success";
    }
```

However on submission my model only holds the values which were updated on the form and excludes the rest

`{user=User [getId()=0, getName()=Bob, getAddress()=42 Wallaby Way, getPhone()=7563434444, getManager()=null}`

None of the predefined fields are populated, which throws an error as the user ID cannot be null or 0 on submission. I'm looking for away to include all fields updated and nonupdated upon my form submit, but I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

So far I've read about Flash and Redirect Attributes which might be what I need. Any thoughts?

EDIT: As Neil McGuigan explained, I should be using `@SessionAttributes`. What I needed were Model Attributes that would stay accessible through the entire session and not just a single GET or POST. This can be done with Session Attributes.

Comment: `<form action="/saveUser{id}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
</form>` are you missing a `/` after `/saveUser`. Should it be `/saveUser/{id}` ?

Comment: Just a typo my slash is in there but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only partially updating a record, the only correct and secure way is to put it in session. Use [@SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) (it goes just above your controller).

```
@SessionAttributes("user")
```

You then don't need to fetch the user from the db in your `saveUser` method.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it's a typo at your end here,

```
<form action="/saveUser{id}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
</form>
```

are you missing a`/` after `/saveUser`. Shouldn't it be `/saveUser/{id}`?

Comment: Just a typo, my controller is called fine with /saveUser/{id} but you're right